# Zoom--why does it stop so short of the primitive here?

Tags: 3d-view

1. Start a new model
2. Shift D
3. Esc
4. Tools!Vector X:  -30
5. Manually pan the new faraway duplicate cube into the center of the screen
6. Manually zoom into that.  Zooming stops far short of it, is prevented from further nearing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you zoom with your mouse wheel?

This behavior is because the zoom you're using is based on a focus point, which is set on the first object. There are two ways to get around:

- set your focus point to your other object with <kbd>Numpad .</kbd>
- use a "dolly zoom", a zoom which moves your view and its focus point as the same time, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Middle mouse button drag</kbd>

Comment: Thanks.  Your second suggestion works for me on this ThinkPad with a desk mouse attached.  (I have a question about the Numpad .--how is that done on a laptop keyboard?)

Comment: Check this : https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/preferences/input.html#emulate-numpad